# how to convert two dimensional integer array elements into string in c#?

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, unityscript

i would like to save my grid positions  of 4*4  grid with integer before quitting game.

I thought i could convert array into string and save it using player preferences for next use.

i saved  the numbers in two dimensional  integer array. now how to convert it into string in c#.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you posted some code, but the simplest method is to deserialise your objects to XML and store the result. Then you can serialise them back in when the game reloads.   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/mt656718.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `StringBuilder` when you convert your array into `string`. You can split every element in row by `","` (or any other symbol) and rows can be splited by `"."` (or any other symbol), so when you will parse string to `int[,]` array you don't need to know the array sizes:

```
public string ArrayToString(int[,] toConvert)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int a = 0; a < toConvert.GetLength(0);a++)
    {
        for (int b = 0; b < toConvert.GetLength(1);b++)
        {
            sb.Append(toConvert[a,b].ToString() + ",");
        }

        sb.Append(".");
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Then you can restore your array from string:

```
public int[,] ArrayFromString(string toConvert)
{
    string[] rows = toConvert.Split('.');
    string[] elements = rows[0].Split(',');

    int[,] result = new int[rows.Length, elements.Length];        

    for (int a = 0; a < rows.Length; a++)
    {
        string[] items = rows[a].Split(',');

        for (int b = 0; b < items.Length; b++)
        {
            result[a,b] = Convert.ToInt32(items[b]);
        }
    }       

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have your result ready in `temp` variable below,

```
var output = new string[temp.GetUpperBound(0)+1];
for (int i = 0; i<=temp.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder(temp.GetUpperBound(1)+1);
    for (int j = 0; j<=temp.GetUpperBound(1); j++)
        sb.Append(temp[i,j]);
    output[i] = sb.ToString();
}
```

Try this.